# Can a balun work below rated voltage?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have a balun of rated voltage 20V; however, my transmitted voltage is approximately 1V. Would the balun operate under this condition?

In the data sheet of the balun only the rated voltage and the max voltage (20V and 120V, respectively) are given.

Comment: [Possibly related question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/191275/61834) on EE SE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.  It would help to know your application, as I designed baluns in a very specific case (shield current suppression).  If you are using a simple centre-tapped transformer as your balun, then of course you can use it under the rated voltage - it won't arc and the magnetic current would be less.